# Java Exception Handling with additional information

Tags: java, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625672/java-exception-handling)

In Java, is it possible to print in console the error code line number with error information means:

```
try {
    // something
} catch(Exception e) {
    // modify this one to print line number of error with additional info
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep.

```
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or you could simply throw the exception, that'll also get you a stack trace.

Answer (score 5):

Just use

`e.printStackTrace();`

or let the exception bubble up, if you want your program to halt on the exception.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for `e.printStackTrace()`.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you don't want the complete stack trace, the Exception method [getStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29) gives you an array of [StackTraceElements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html). You can interrogate these for line numbers, file names etc. and generate some custom informative message highlighting the source of the exception.

Answer (score 3):

`Throwable` (which `Exception` extends) has a method `getStackTrace()` which returns a `StackTraceElement[]`, each of which includes a method getLineNumber().

So:

```
e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()
```