# Can't get a string from nested downloaded JSON

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I'm getting a JSON from the server:

```
                JSONObject vkjson = response.json;
```

I have tried to make it a string and check via LogCat to make sure it works - and yeah, it 100% works.
But it is nested:

```
{"response":{"first_name":"...","last_name":"..."} }
```

I have tried to do this:

```
       String result = vkjson.getJSONObject("response").getString("first_name");
```

But IDE doesn't like the getJSONObject part and underlines it. IDE says:

> Unhandled exception in org.json.JSONException

What's wrong? Is it because the JSON is loading from the server or the code is incorrect?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unhandled exception in org.json.JSONException

Mean that the method can throw a `JSONException` and you have to handle it.

So you have to:

```
try {
     String result = vkjson.getJSONObject("response").getString("first_name");
} catch (JSONException exception){
            //Handle exception here
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you!
I thought it means that something is wrong with data being sent to a method

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code other than not handling the `JSONException` which is potentially thrown (i.e. what would happen if there isn't an object called "response").

You need to look at exception handling and wrap this code in a `try .. catch` block or otherwise deal with the exception.

[Java exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625672/java-exception-handling)

Answer (score 0):

Do this-:

```
try
{
 JSONObject vkjson = response.json;

  //More code related to json
}

catch(JsonException e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
                if(jsonObject != null)
                {
                    if (jsonObject.has("response")) {
                        JSONObject responseObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
                        String firstName = responseObject.getString("first_name");
                        Log.d("Tag",firstName);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```