# Get Method name with parameters and its values on exception in Java

Tags: java

I have a sample program as follows

```java
public static void enterText(WebElement loc, String value) {
    try {
        loc.clear();
        System.out.println("Text cleared successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // exception handling
    }
}
```

On executing `loc.clear()`, a runtime exception occurs.
Is there a way I can get the method name with parameters after exception happens.
I need to get this `enterText(WebElement loc, String value)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625672/java-exception-handling)

Answer (score 0):

You shall print the trace of the exception via this call: `e.printStackTrace()` inside `catch` block.

Comment: No..that would not give me the argument details wit which the method was invoked.

Comment: @chinnuNish You can print the arguments in the `catch` block if you need

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a "print" statement in the `catch` block.

```java
public static void enterText(WebElement loc, String value) {
    try {
        loc.clear();
        System.out.println("Text cleared successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.printf("ERROR: enterText( %s , %s )%n", loc, value);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```